# unable to update cart table after deleting with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax

When I delete item from my cart. Item deleted on backend but on front end webpage it shows json data

```json
{"added": false, "removed": true, "CartItemsCount": 3}
```

and not showing actual cart (table).
Code is attached in [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mzMB.png). Please help if you can, thanks.

In console log of chrome, this msg come for nano seconds and disapear..
`resource interpreted as document but transferred with mime type application/json django`

django view for cart update ( delete or add item )

```py
def cart_update(request):
    contact_id = request.POST['contact_id']
    obj_product = Contacts.objects.get(id=contact_id)
    cart_obj, new_obj = Cart.objects.new_or_get(request)
    if obj_product in cart_obj.contacts.all():
        cart_obj.contacts.remove(obj_product)
        added = False
    else:
        cart_obj.contacts.add(obj_product)
        added = True

    request.session['cart_item'] = cart_obj.contacts.count()
    if request.is_ajax:
        json_data = {
            "added": added,
            "removed": not added,
            "CartItemsCount": cart_obj.contacts.count(),
        }
        return JsonResponse(json_data, status=200)

    else:
        print('HTTP referer')
        return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))  #redirect to same page
```

django view for getting cart data with api

```py
def cart_api(request):
    cart_obj, new_obj = Cart.objects.new_or_get(request)
    products =[{'name':x.firstname,
                'id':x.id,
                'price':x.price}
               for x in cart_obj.contacts.all()]
    cart_data = {'products':products, 'subtotal':cart_obj.subtotal, 'total':cart_obj.total}
    return JsonResponse(cart_data)
```

javascript

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

    console.log("Not In Cart")
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var productForm = $(".form-product-ajax")
        productForm.on('submit', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var thisForm = $(this)
            var actionEndPoint = thisForm.attr("action");
            var httpMethod = thisForm.attr("method");
            var formData = thisForm.serialize();
            var CurrentPath = window.location.href
            $.ajax({
                url: actionEndPoint,
                method: httpMethod,
                data: formData,
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log("success")
                    refreshCart()
                    var submitSpan = thisForm.find(".submit-span")
                    if (CurrentPath.indexOf("cart/") == -1) {
                        if (data.added) {
                            submitSpan.html("<button type='submit' name='submit' class='btn btn-danger'>Remove</button>")
                        } else {
                            submitSpan.html("<button type='submit' name='submit' class='btn btn-success'>Add to Cart</button>")
                        }
                    } else {}
                    var itemCount = $(".navbar-cart-itemcount")
                    itemCount.text(data.CartItemsCount)
                    console.log("Testing")
                },
                error: function(errorData) {
                    console.log("Eror")
                    console.log(errorData)
                }
            })
        })



        function refreshCart() {
            var cartTable = $(".cart-home")
            var cartBody = cartTable.find(".cart-body")
            var productRows = cartBody.find(".cart-product")
            var currentUrl = window.location.href
            var refreshCartUrl = "/api/cart/"
            var refreshCartMethod = "GET";
            var data = {};
            $.ajax({
                url: refreshCartUrl,
                method: refreshCartMethod,
                data: data,
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data, "Your Data Here")
                    var HiddenCartItemRemoveForm = $(".cart-item-remove-form")
                    console.log("showig Cart Item.");
                    if (data.products.length > 0) {
                        i = data.products.length
                        productRows.html("")
                        $.each(data.products, function(index, value) {
                            var newCartItemRemove = HiddenCartItemRemoveForm.clone()
                            newCartItemRemove.css = ("display", "block")
                            newCartItemRemove.find(".cart-item-product-id").val(value.id)
                            HiddenCartItemRemoveForm.find(".cart-item-product-id").val(value.id)
                            cartBody.prepend("<tr><th scope='row'>" + i + "</th><td colspan=2>" + value.name + newCartItemRemove.html() + "</td><td>" + value.price + "</td></tr>")
                            i--
                        })
                        cartBody.find(".cart-subtotal").text(data.subtotal)
                        cartBody.find(".cart-total").text(data.total)
                        var itemCount = $(".navbar-cart-itemcount")
                        itemCount.text(data.CartItemsCount)
                    } else {
                        window.locatin.href = currentUrl
                    }
                },
                error: function(errorData) {
                    console.log("error")
                    console.log(errorData)
                }
            })
        }
        if (window.location.href.indexOf("cart") > -1) {
            refreshCart()
            console.log("Current Cart")
        }
    })
</script>
```

error msg: `{"added": false, "removed": true, "CartItemsCount": 3}`

[Cart update view function of Django](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mzMB.png)

[jquery Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GsazP.png)

[update Cart function of jquery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSgUP.png)

[api-cart view function Django](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrM8h.png)

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1lb8.png)

Comment: when I Delete Item from standerd HTML form using same cart_update() view then cart table automaticaly created and displayed on page but with jquery with same Django view it only show this reponse (json) on page. it should update the cart table. I still dont know why.